# Convert Object type to a DateTimeOffset

Tags: c#, object, type-conversion

I have a dictionary of string and object, for integer part I can use 
Convert.ToInt32() , but for DateTimeOffset, I can't seem to find any (there's Convert.ToDateTime() but I'm afraid the Offset part would be trimmed), I tried searching the stackoverflow and web but nothing can be used.

Please help.

Update:

How I initialize the Dictionary and Watch window result.
StoreID is int, the other is DateTimeOffset.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried DateTimeOffset.Parse() ?

Comment: @DCCoder I'll try that, but the object needs to be converted with .ToString() first, I wonder if there are any way to directly convert object type to DateTimeOffset type. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You can either use DateTimeOffset.Parse() or if the object was originally a DateTimeOffset just cast it to that.

Comment: @DCCoder I've tried typecasting it, something like DateTimeOffset a = (DateTimeOffset) obj; But I get Specified cast is not valid error.

Comment: Can you show how you are getting the data into the dictionary?

Comment: What is the actual type of the object? (`object.GetType()`)

Comment: If you look at the object in a watch window in the debugger, you will see the type of the object. Then, once you have that (and share it with us by editing your question), there should be a path forward

Comment: @Corey sorry for late reply `Data = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    {"ID", Id}, // int
                    {"Date", DateTimeOffset.Now} //DateTimeOffset
                };`

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you are trying to store multiple types in an object like this?  Why not create an object that can store all of that information and then you can store it in a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I think that storing multiple types of data like this is probably A Bad Idea - see below for alternatives.  C# is strongly-typed (for the most part) and works best when it knows ahead of time what is going on with the types.  But it does have ways of determining what type is actually stored in an `object` and let you cast back into proper typed references.

In this case the best fit for your issue seems to be the [`is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is).  This will let you test whether an `object` (or reference, or...) is compatible with the specified type:

```
object val = task.Data["StartDate"];
if (val is DateTimeOffset)
{
    var dto = (DateTimeOffset)val;
    // do something with the DateTimeOffset
}
```

In C# version 7 they introduced a pattern matching variant that lets you abbreviate the type conversion:

```
object val = task.Data["StartDate"];
if (val is DateTimeOffset dto)
{
    // do something
}
```

This works for both reference and value types, and will pass any valid non-converting typecast.  It's handy for testing interfaces on types in generic code too:

```
if (someobject is IDisposable disp)
{
    disp.Dispose();
}
```

---

In general though I would avoid your dictionary of objects as much as possible.  While there are some cases where it is valid, those cases are fairly rare.  The `ViewBag` in ASP.NET MVC for instance is one case where it kind of works, but there are other ways that could have been done.

The why is simple: [boxing and unboxing values takes time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing#performance).  Testing the types of values takes time that you mostly don't need to waste if you're using static types.  And you don't have to worry about someone sticking a string where you're expecting an int.

For your own code the more normal case would be to define a class to hold the task data and pass that:

```
public class TaskData
{
    public int StoreID { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

... and use it as:

```
task.Data = new TaskData { StoreID = storeID, startDate = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(3) };
```

Now you task will know what it's dealing with directly, no casting required.  And no chance that someone will come along and assign some wacky value that your code doesn't know how to deal with into one of your variables.  Or forget to use `DateTimeOffset` and use `DateTime` instead, with no complaint at all from the compiler.

If you're really averse to defining all sorts of classes just for this sort of thing you can use the C#7 [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) types to do something similar:

```
// in your task class:
public (int StoreID, DateTimeOffset StartDate) Data { get; set; }

// initialize in other code:
task.Data = (storeID, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(3));
```

In the above the type is defined at compile time with decorations for the names and such so that you can use them elsewhere in your code, but they are effectively syntactic sugar used by the compiler and not available at runtime via reflection etc.  Think of it as a handy short-hand for simplifying certain things.

Of course if you have a genuine need to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` for this data then go ahead.  Just ask yourself if the overheads are worth the effort.